# variables duplicated in python threading class

Tags: python, multithreading, global-variables

I'm very new to python.. I'm writing a class to create multiple threads for an  application that I'm building for my Raspberry Pi (hence the GPIO pins). I have this basically working by pulling some data from a DB, creating an instance of the class which runs a thread, passing two variables to it (deviceGPIO and duration), and pausing some time.

Basically the problem is that my thread instance is duplicating for the second two times it's run, despite unique values being pulled from the DB and passed to the class. I'm a little confused around the use of kwargs and args in general so would appreciate any help in this space..

**The class / thread code:**

```
class MyThreadWithArgs(threading.Thread):

        def __init__(self, deviceGPIO="default value", duration="default value", group=None, target=None, name=None,
                     args=(), verbose=None, **kwargs):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self, group=group, target=target, name=name,
                                      verbose=verbose)

            self.deviceGPIO = deviceGPIO
            self.duration = duration

            return

        def run(self):

            logging.debug('Current GPIO pin: %s', deviceGPIO)

            #pause for some time... 
            time.sleep(duration)


        logging.debug('ending')

        return
```

**Calling the instance:**

The following is called within the results of a DB query (eg each class is created based on each DB row returned)

```
for row in rows:

    duration = int(row["programDuration"]) 
    deviceGPIO = int(row["deviceGPIO"])  

    t = MyThreadWithArgs(args=(), kwargs={deviceGPIO, duration})
    t.start()
```

**Results:**

The following is the results (python logging output)

```
(Thread-1  ) Current GPIO pin: 12
(Thread-2  ) Current GPIO pin: 16
(Thread-3  ) Current GPIO pin: 16
(Thread-1  ) ending
(Thread-2  ) ending
(Thread-3  ) ending
```

I've tried clearing the variable passed to the class, without success, as the 2nd two instances are displaying duplicated results (despite having unique DB records being passed to the class).

Am I missing something simple here?

**UPDATE**

I updated the script using the feedback provided, although it still continued to display the duplicate values despite my changes. In the end I used the following code, although rather than using the `deviceGPIO` variable, I used `self.deviceGPIO` as the variable. I'm not sure why this worked - I'm keen to understand where I went wrong, and why using `self.deviceGPIO` has made a difference compared to the original variable with the same value.

```
class MyThreadWithArgs(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, deviceGPIO="default value", duration="default value", **kwargs):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, **kwargs)

        self.deviceGPIO = deviceGPIO
        self.duration = duration



    def run(self):        


        logging.debug('Current GPIO pin: %s', self.deviceGPIO)  

        #pause for some time... 
        time.sleep(duration)

        logging.debug('ending')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing in your variables correctly.

```
t = MyThreadWithArgs(args=(), kwargs={deviceGPIO, duration})
```

creates two new keyword arguments; effectively setting the `kwargs` argument of the `__init__` method to:

```
{'args': (), 'kwargs': {<deviceGPIO value>, <duration value>}}
```

with the `kwargs` value being a *set*, not a dictionary.

In the `__init__` method you are using the default values for `deviceGPIO` and `duration` instead, because you never gave specific arguments for those two values.

Use:

```
t = MyThreadWithArgs(deviceGPIO=deviceGPIO, duration=duration)
```

to create your thread subclass instances, passing in the `deviceGPIO` and `duration` values to the keyword arguments explicitly.

If you don't plan on specifying the rest of the `Thread.__init__` arguments, you can leave those out altogether, as the `Thread` class itself already has defaults for these:

```
class MyThreadWithArgs(threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self, deviceGPIO="default value", duration="default value"):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)

            self.deviceGPIO = deviceGPIO
            self.duration = duration
```

Note that the `return` is not required here either. You can always add arguments back in, or just use:

```
class MyThreadWithArgs(threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self, deviceGPIO="default value", duration="default value", **kwargs):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self, **kwargs)

            self.deviceGPIO = deviceGPIO
            self.duration = duration
```

to pass any extra keyword arguments on to the `Thread._init__()` method, allowing you to create a new `MyThreadWithArgs()` instance adding in keyword arguments such as `group` or `name` as needed.

Comment: Thanks Martijn - I made your suggested changes, although they didn't resolve the issue. In the end I used `self.deviceGPIO` rather than `deviceGPIO` and the issue was resolved. Where did I go wrong initially with the use of the variable?

Comment: @user2935991: you were using a global variable `deviceGPIO` in `run`, which I had missed as I was focusing on the way you were calling the `__init__` method. It also explains why your code worked at all (I thought perhaps the `"default value"` was a placeholder just for the question).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. To confirm, is the correct process to use global variables within my class, or should I change the use of the `self.deviceGPIO` variable (which I assume is a local variable to the class)?

Comment: @user2935991: You definitely should use `self.deviceGPIO`, as that is an attribute on the current instance. You have several instances, each with their own attribute, while the global would be shared among all the instances.